# Django: AttributeError: module 'User.views' has no attribute 'User'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a few apps within my Django project and all of them seem to be working, except for the User app. All the apps are installed in the settings. Whenever I type "python manage.py runserver", I see a long line of code that ends with this:

```
File "/Users/Name/Desktop/Project_Name/MyProject/User/urls.py", line 5,                  
in <module>
url(r'Home/', views.User, name='Home'),
AttributeError: module 'User.views' has no attribute 'User'
```

MyProject/urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
    from django.contrib import admin

        urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^$', include('Home.urls')),
        url(r'^Application', include('Application.urls')),
        url(r'^Login', include('Login.urls')),
        url(r'^User', include('User.urls')),
    ]
```

User/urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
    from User import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'Home/', views.User, name='Home'),
        url(r'Matrices/', views.User, name='Matrices'),
    ]
```

User/views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render

    def Home(request):
        return render(request, 'Home.html')

    def Matrices(request):
        return render(request, 'Matrices.html')
```

If I remove "url(r'^User', include('User.urls'))" from MyProjects/urls.py, everything is working fine (but of course I cannot access the urls from User app). All the other apps have only one "url" and only User app has multiple urls. Is that where the issue lies?

Would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

user/views.py has no method User, you have only two methods HOME and MATRICES, and you are trying to call a method named User doing this `

```
url(r'Matrices/', views.User, name='Matrices')
```

To solve your problem you need call an available method from user/views.py HOME or MATRICES like this

```
url(r'ThisIsTheNameOfTheUrlNotTheMethod/', views.Home, name='Home'),
```

or

```
url(r'matrices/', views.Matrices, name='Matrices'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your urlpatterns needs to use the views.py functions like

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'Home/$', views.Home, name='Home'),
        url(r'Matrices/$', views.Matrices, name='Matrices'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`url(r'Home/', views.User, name='Home')`

From the above code, try removing the space between the comma and the words `views.user`. That fixed my problem.

Illustration: code should look like;
`url(r'Home/',views.User, name='Home')`. no space between `comma` and `views.user`

Answer (score 0):

in your `User/urls.py`

replace the following line:

```
from User import views
```

with the following line:

```
from . import views
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey if someone else is facing this error and cant solve using solution of this question. You can solve using saving your `views.py` of your app before running.